# Async await working fine on ctlr+F5 but NOT when I move from 1 page to another

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using *Node.js* server for HTTP request purpose.  So when i press Ctrl+F5  the *async,await* works as it is supposed to but when i move between pages and come back to the same page which i am trying to check . it doesn't work the same way. Data has been fetched in both cases from REST API but on ctrl+F5 it waits out while on normal moving from page to page it doesn't wait and as a result doesn't show the HTML code generated from JS even tho it is there -__-  ...

JS code Given below

```
async function addAllSubjects() {


    await fetch('http://localhost:2000/getallsubjects')
        .then(async(res) => await res.json())
        .then(async(obj) => {
            let html = `<div style="width: 500;"> <select  name="subjects_select" class="selectpicker dropdown-dense" multiple data-width="100%" data-height="50%" data-size="${obj.length}" data-selected-text-format="count > 3" data-style="btn-primary" title="Choose one of the following..." data-actions-box="true" data-header="Select Subjects" data-live-search="true"
              data-live-search-placeholder="Search ..."> <optgroup label="Subjects" id="dynamic_subjects"> `  // to set style of this selector u need to set styles through css file such as in asssign-course.css
              let options =  await obj.map((value, index) => `<option value="${value.sbt_id}">${value.sbt_id}-${value.sbt_name}-${value.semester}</option>`)
            options = options.join('\n') + "</optgroup>"
            html += options + "</select></div>"
            console.log(obj[1])
            document.getElementById("form-group").innerHTML = html
        }).catch(err => console.error(err))




}
async function addallteacherswithids() {
    await fetch('http://localhost:2000/allteachernameid')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(obj => {
            console.log(obj[0].t_id + " Teacher check")
            let html = obj.map((value, index) => {

                let a = (value.t_name + "," + value.t_id)
                console.log(a + "test checj teacher")
                if (value.t_id === "") return ""
                return `<option value="${index}">${a}</option>`

            }).join("\n")
            document.getElementById('teachernameid').innerHTML = html


        })


}
```

**=> Node.js terminal on Ctrl+F5** : -   [image: Node.js terminal on Ctrl+F5]

**=> Node.js terminal on movement to some other page and then back to current page** : -  [image]

Browser Google Chrome version: -  78.0.3904.108
OS : -  Windows 10

Side Note *These functions are being called in the Js file below , I didn't present them here because it would simple add too much needless code to the question*

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: And ... What's the problem actually?

Comment: up in the JS code,  addAllSubjects()  function generates HTML , which generates in both cases but  it is visible in case of page refresh via CTRL+F5 but not when move between different pages and come back to the same test page where addAllSubjects() is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I checked out stuff and turn out it was the cache issue. Browsers including incognito mode were retrieving data from cache which was causing issues like 304 error. So I moved all src and links in header  to the end part of the body and then i added these meta tags in header

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

and as a result the error got resolved..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59135040/9256432   comments section part is where i got the idea for what might have been the case ...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try simplifying your code to something like,
`const obj = await (await fetch('http://localhost:2000/getallsubjects')).json()`
This can be wrapped in a `try/catch` block and the html modification code can follow.

The main difference is that you get 304s when navigating, so just make sure that 304s are handled appropriately and the obj always has a value.

Also check the network tab on your browser to see the type of content you get back from the XHR requests.

Comment: I will check it out now

Comment: I don't know why is 304 coming .. and  try and catch stuff didn't solve the issue tho . yet is is a cleaner way to do it , thanks for that .  But i couldn't manage to check out error 304 cause.  .. . ..  am working on it

Comment: Cant find the root cause .. All i see is that in CTRL + 5 case header have Connection: keep alive   while in other case there is nothing as connection , and data in both functions is same  *in context to XHR*

Comment: @MuhammadUmarKhan the 304 means that the content has not changed, based on the cached copy of the data held in the browser. If the server sends back `etag`  *response headers* or the client sends the second time *request header* `If-Modified-Since` then this check will happen on the server and it will respond with 304 if there is no change.
To prevent this, either don't send an `etag` from server or on the client side skip cache eg by adding a timestamp on the end `fetch(\`http://....${Date.now()\`)`, or using `no-store`, `fetch('http://....', {cache: "no-store"})`.

Comment: yes that soled the error 304 yet the part where i needed data to show up in time is still missing. it is in HTML which can be viewed on inspect. But not showing up in time because page loads faster then its components some how.

Comment: @MuhammadUmarKhan i see, then this is no longer an issue with async/await and data retrieval, but related to the timing of the components rendering etc. 
You'll need a separate question for that, explaining the tech stack you're using, the code running and how it's best to handle that etc

Comment: Sorry for late reply ,  But hmmm.... I would like to surf a bit more maybe i can find something before i go for another ..   Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using `async/await` is wrong, this is not how `async/await` is used. `.map` is not promise so you don't have to use the await in `.map`

This is how it is used, please read async/await [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
async function addAllSubjects() {
    try {
        const request = await fetch('http://localhost:2000/getallsubjects')
        const obj = await request.json()
        let html = `<div style="width: 500;"> <select  name="subjects_select" class="selectpicker dropdown-dense" multiple data-width="100%" data-height="50%" data-size="${obj.length}" data-selected-text-format="count > 3" data-style="btn-primary" title="Choose one of the following..." data-actions-box="true" data-header="Select Subjects" data-live-search="true"
        data-live-search-placeholder="Search ..."> <optgroup label="Subjects" id="dynamic_subjects"> `
        let options =  await obj.map((value, index) => `<option value="${value.sbt_id}">${value.sbt_id}-${value.sbt_name}-${value.semester}</option>`)
        options = options.join('\n') + "</optgroup>"
        html += options + "</select></div>"
        return html
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return null
    }

}


addAllSubjects().then(html => {
    if(html !== null) document.getElementById('form-group').innerHTML = html
})
```

Comment: Hi , Yes I understand that part  but I am too confused at the moment to think clearly , Yet that didn't solve the issue. I think its issue with page redirection , as i noticed same behavior with other pages as well.

Comment: error 304 is still existing while on page redirect which I am not able to remove for the moment.